# Retrieve all Routes up to a certain Route

Tags: angular, routes

Is it possible to retrieve all the Routes that have been taken up to a certain route in a page?

This way, if I reach a certain route and then want to specify a route to go back to if said route is hit, I can search the route array for it and then navigate to it.

Thanks

Comment: Like a "history" of recently visited pages or something?

Comment: Yes. A history of visited routes thus far. If I visit a bad route (unauthorized for example), I can then say, "okay, go to the route that was previous to the `unauthorized` one, and then go there"

Comment: Are you redirecting somewhere on a bad request?

Comment: @Drewness, yes. I'm currently using `router.navigateByUrl('errorPage')` to bring up the error component. From there, I'd like to give the user the ability to acknowledge the error, click an OK button, and then be taken back to the previous route before landing on the unauthorized route. We currently send them back to the login page but I'd like to handle the error more gracefully.

Comment: Is it possible to store a global variable, unique for each 'route' when you reach it via your component?  Then you would know which one is assigned prior to the error page.